# Custom Time Formatting what does 0: do?

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, datetime-format

[Custom Date and Time Format Strings on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Link above seems to use {0:MM/dd/yy H:mm:ss zzz} a lot.

I understand all the letters and formatting options but I can't seem to find what the preceding "0:" is for?

Comment: those are the placeholders for the variables. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26etazsy(v=vs.95).aspx and scroll down to "Composite Formatting"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `{0}` is a composite formatting placeholder, meaning the first item in the format value list. For details, see [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26etazsy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), in particular, the section called "Composite Formatting" near the bottom, or the larger article specifically about [Composite Formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx). But, to summarize:

In .NET there are two kinds of string formatting you can do: `ToString` formatting and composite formatting. Both of them use the same custom format string syntax.

When you have a single object, like a `DateTime` variable, and you call `DateTime.ToString()` on that object, you can pass a formatting string and it will apply to that object, and format it according to your pattern. But if you have more than one object and you want to build a complex string that includes their values, you instead call [`String.Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx). That function expects a "format string" that contains placeholders where the variable bits go, which look like `{0:g}` or `{5:MM/dd/yy}` or something. The remainder of the parameters to `String.Format` is a list of variables. The `{0}` placeholder is the first variable, `{5}` is the 6th, etc.

Comment: I understand composite formatting. But just to make sure I understand what you're saying. Is this is just a preference? Because when I use dates as string I usually first declare a string then fill the string with the date formatted. I then call my string into a placeholder in my String.Format. You're saying this is just a way to avoid filling a string variable ahead of time? and place the format option in my placeholder?

Comment: Yes. If you pass a `DateTime` to `String.Format()` it uses the same formatting logic as `DateTime.ToString()`, so there's no need to call it separately. You can do e.g. `String.Format("Today is: {0:MM/dd/yy}", DateTime.Today)`